# ObjectMapper writeValueAsString() changing key names when writing to String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to turn a DTO to string to store in a database. I am calling:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeFactory factory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
        // type of key of response map
        JavaType stringType = factory.constructType(String.class);
        // type of value of response map
        JavaType listOfDtosType = factory.constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, SummonerRankedInfoDTOEntry.class);
        // create type of map
        JavaType responseType = factory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, stringType, listOfDtosType);
        try {
            assert json != null;
            Map<String, List<SummonerRankedInfoDTOEntry>> response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, responseType);
            summonerRankedInfoDTO.setIntegerSummonerRankedInfoDTOEntryMap(response);
            logger.info("Json has been de-serialized" + summonerRankedInfoDTO.getIntegerSummonerRankedInfoDTOEntryMap());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return summonerRankedInfoDTO;
```

on my DTO which is: http://codebeautify.org/javaviewer/cb5e233b.

Notice the fields:

```
LeagueDTOEntry {
      division = 'V ', isFreshBlood = false, isHotStreak = false, isInactive = false, isVeteran = false, leaguePoints = 0, losses = 32, miniSeries = null, playerOrTeamId = 'TEAM - 77 b4b970 - 5e e2 - 11e4 - 9 d98 - c81f66db96d8 ', playerOrTeamName = 'Team Invertebrate ', wins = 32
     }
```

the isFreshBlood, isHotStreak, isInactive and isVeteran fields.

I call the above code and log the string it returns, which is: https://jsonblob.com/56852fd6e4b01190df4650cd

All the fields above have lost the "is" part: freshBlood, hotStreak... etc.

I can post my DTOs but I've been looking for a long time and have no idea why it's changing their names. I don't think I ever named them without the "is" as the "is" is on the values returned from an API call.

Any help is appreciated, not sure how to make this question less confusing...

EDIT: My LeagueEntryDTO is:

```
private String division;

private boolean isFreshBlood;
private boolean isHotStreak;
private boolean isInactive;
private boolean isVeteran;

private int leaguePoints;

private MiniSeriesDTOEntry miniSeries;
private String playerOrTeamId;
private String playerOrTeamName;
private int wins;
private int losses;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LeagueDTOEntry{" +
            "division='" + division + '\'' +
            ", isFreshBlood=" + isFreshBlood +
            ", isHotStreak=" + isHotStreak +
            ", isInactive=" + isInactive +
            ", isVeteran=" + isVeteran +
            ", leaguePoints=" + leaguePoints +
            ", losses=" + losses +
            ", miniSeries=" + miniSeries +
            ", playerOrTeamId='" + playerOrTeamId + '\'' +
            ", playerOrTeamName='" + playerOrTeamName + '\'' +
            ", wins=" + wins +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: Post your LeagueDTOEntry object, at least the field names, you dont need to show the getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to keep the `is` prefixes rather than respecting the standard JavaBean conventions, annotate your getters with (for example)

```
@JsonProperty("isInactive")
```

Also, your JSON logic is way too complex. You should just have to do

```
Map<String, List<SummonerRankedInfoDTOEntry>> response = 
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(
        json, 
        new TypeReference<Map<String, List<SummonerRankedInfoDTOEntry>>>() {});
```

Comment: The `is` is in the JSON i'm getting back from the API. I wanted to keep all my code the same as the json i'm getting, but everything to do with `is` is fine, until it just changes when it gets inputted into the database.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain how this would work - the deserialize from API String to DTO is fine, but when I serialize it is changing the isInactive to inactive. I think I worded my question a little bit confusingly, apologies.

Comment: I have added the annotation on my getters, and I also originally had annotations on the fields before, but I couldn't get it to work either way. When changing from DTO to String i thought it should just use the variable names unless specified otherwise? Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question, and post a minimal, complete example reproducing the problem. Here's one, and it doesn't reproduce your problem: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/35f08a54a8b5dbc48eb6

Comment: Hi, apologies I have been busy recently, I went back to your answer and realised I had not cleared my database with the old data... Your solution did work, Sorry! Thank you very much for your help, i'll look up it works as I did not know Jackson mapper used the getters and setters! Thanks again.